# Auto sort and format and Excel

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office, spreadsheet

I have a table of clients in Excel, and I want to be able to add new client into the last row of the table and excel will sort the table automatically so that the client's name will be sorted in alphabetical order.

Also, that the format will be similar to the previous line. for example, the second column is DOB, so I want the format to be the same as the previous row MM/DD/YYYY

Thanks

Comment: `Re: AutoSort` -> you will need some VBA for this. Excel won't just sort something unless you tell it to - or program it too. `Re: Formatting` -> You can pre-format as many cells as you like, even if they are not filled in. Just select the range and format as you wish.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Ok, how do I do it will VBA? Can't find the right solution in VBA.

Comment: Use the `Worksheet_Change` event and check that the change is occurring in the column where you enter the new client. Then set the range to be sorted and sort. If you get stuck, edit your post with the code you are trying and where it's not working. Then we can help you get unstuck!

Comment: For the format, format the whole column as MM/DD/YYYY and it will stay that way until you copy paste on top of it.

Comment: For the sort, do you have any other columns that need to be filled before your client name is whisked away to another row? In addition, is typing Alt ASA (for 2010) or Alt AA (for 2007) that long that you need a macro to avoid it?

Comment: Auto-sort will be super-confusing if anyone other than you is going to be using this. I would use a "Sort" button instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the attached code in your worksheet module and it will sort your column A automatically.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'turn off updates to speed up code execution
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .DisplayAlerts = False
End With

If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(1)) Is Nothing Then

    With ActiveSheet.Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:X" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

    Columns("B").NumberFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY"

End If

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .DisplayAlerts = True
End With


End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, it works great. but I have a question. I have four columns to fill. once I put the client name and want to move to the second column, it sorts the table but then I"m not on the same row to continue with the other information. is there a way to sort it only after I got to the last column?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it. I changed the line. **If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(4)) Is Nothing Then**

Answer (score 0):

Here's a piece of VBA that would auto-add your table as soon as the first cell on the last row gets typed in. You would have to provide IsChangeInLastLineOfStrRange function and call AddEmptyRowWhenFull from the change-event. It might need tweaking since I removed some code from it. The original has a recursion timer to prevent ... well ... recursion.

```
Public Sub AddEmptyRowWhenFull(SheetName As String, Area As String, Target As Range)
    Dim rngDatabase As Range

    With Sheets(SheetName)
        If IsChangeInLastLineOfStrRange(SheetName, Area, Target) _
        And Target.Value <> "" Then
            Set rngDatabase = .Range(Area)
            AddEmptyRow rngDatabase, rngDatabase.Rows.Count
        End If
    End With
End Sub


Public Sub AddEmptyRow(Database As Range, RowPosition As Long, Optional ClearLine As Boolean = True)
    Dim bScreenupdate, iCalculation As Integer
    Dim colnum As Long, markrow As Long
    Dim bUpdate As Boolean

    bScreenupdate = Application.ScreenUpdating
    iCalculation = Application.Calculation

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    With Database
         If RowPosition < .Rows.Count Then
            .Rows(RowPosition - 0).Copy                     'Insert in and after data
        .Rows(RowPosition + 1).Insert shift:=xlDown
         Else
            .Rows(RowPosition - 0).Copy                     'Add line at end by inserting before last line
            .Rows(RowPosition - 0).Insert shift:=xlDown     ' to prevent cell formatting below it to be copied too
             RowPosition = RowPosition + 1                  'Clear last of the copies
         End If

         If ClearLine = False Then                          'Move cursor down
            ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveCell.row + 1, ActiveCell.column).Activate
         Else
            For colnum = 1 To .Columns.Count                'Preserve formula's
                If Not .Rows(RowPosition).Cells(1, colnum).HasFormula Then 'changed
                       .Rows(RowPosition).Cells(1, colnum).ClearContents
                End If
            Next colnum
         End If

         'Fix rowheight if we shift into other heights

         .Rows(RowPosition + 1).RowHeight = .Rows(RowPosition + 0).RowHeight
    End With

    If bScreenupdate = True Then Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    If Not iCalculation = xlCalculationManual Then Application.Calculation = iCalculation
End Sub
```

Arjen.